# Get topmost view controller in stack without looping through

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I can't loop through my view controllers because I need to only call one method if the current view controller is one in particular. If I loop through, then all methods will get called. I've been using this code:

```
if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for viewController in viewControllers {
                // some process
                if viewController.isKindOfClass(MyViewController) {
                    println("\(viewController) yes it is")
                } else {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
        }
```

Essentially, I don't want to `popViewControllerAnimated` if the current view is on a particular view controller. However because of the loop, it's getting called anyway. How can I just return the current view controller without making this loop?

Comment: Question is bit unclear. Question title and code are contradictory. Do you want top most controller on stack or a specific controller?

Comment: I'm trying to check if the top most controller on stack is a particular controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first and last with following Obj-C methods:

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject]; 
[self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
```

the methods are not available in Swift but easily doable by extending Array so that you can reuse it in the project.

```
extension Array {
    var lastObject: T {
        return self[self.endIndex - 1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So since I needed to see if the current, or top most view controller matched a particular view controller, I converted `self.navigationController?.visibleViewController` to a string and checked if `.rangeofString()` contained the name of the view controller I was looking for. Worked great.

Update: Although this method worked for me, @Gandalf's suggestion below is probably a much safer bet. That works for me too.

Comment: instead of converting the ViewController to string you should have checked it like you are doing in your question code with `isKindOfClass:`